# asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

i am new for asp.net. **i want to develop a simple web application(asp.net+c#) which display 
questions and multiple choice answers and calculate result**. i want to know which one is the best way for me to do it.
i want to use linq to sql.
please guide me.
thanks in advance and **sorry if you feel my question style is bad**.

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Break it down into small questions. Then look for the answers before posting the question. Only if you can't quickly find the answers here should you then post the small questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where you can start

http://www.asp.net/get-started

http://www.asp.net/web-forms

http://www.asp.net/mvc

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/

Start by this examples...

Oh and here is something very close to what you ask

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MultipleChoiceExam.aspx